# How to define defaultProps in React 18 TypeScript without optionals

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Using React functional components, it's recommended to no longer use `Component.defaultProps`. Default props should be defined in the function params itself, like this:

```js
interface Props {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
}

const Component: FC<Props> = ({ foo = 'hello', bar = 'world' }) => {
  return ...
}
```

However this only works when props have an `optional` `?` type, which is then set by the params when a value is undefined. What if I don't want to make my props optional?

For example, this won't work:

```js
interface Props {
  importantProp: string,
}

const ImportantComponent: FC<Props> = ({ importantProp = 'not undefined' }) => {
  return ...
}

// usage
const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
   return <ImportantComponent />
   // ts-error -> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': importantProp.
}
```

Defining this prop as `optional` brings some risks, as it's now also optional when defining its default props. Someone might forget to pass a value to it and now everything will break. (in the worst case):

```js
const ImportantComponent: FC<Props> = ({ importantProp = undefined }) => {}
// We can still set `importantProp` to undefined, which should never happen
```

So, what is a proper solution where default props can be defined without setting them as optional params?

Comment: if someone forgets to pass a value the default will be shown, what is the problem here? What risks are you talking about?

Comment: If someone forgets to pass the value in default props, it can still be undefined.

Comment: And TypeScript still thinks a value could be undefined, which is ofcourse not true since we're defining default props.

Comment: I too am struggling to see the problem. The type on props defines what the component looks like from the outside. Optional means that`<ImportantComponent />` is legal, mandatory means it's illegal. If it's mandatory, then a default value will never matter. If it's optional, then you can write `importantProp = 'not undefined'` so the code inside the component is dealing with a `string`. It's true you're not forced to write `importantProp = 'not undefined'`, but if you forget then typescript knows it's `string | undefined`, and will give an error if you use it as a `string` on later lines.

Comment: So either my TypeScript is not setup properly or I’m missing something. Eg defining an object `const defaultProps: Props = { importantProp: ‘value’ }` and using it as `Component = (props = defaultProps) => {}` doesn’t work with optionals.

Comment: That won't work, no, because `props` is the entire props object, and that's always defined. It's the individual values *inside* the props object that might be undefined. Is that your goal: to store all your defaults in a single predefined object, then apply it? That's unusual, but i could type up an answer of how to do that.

Comment: Well let's say I have a component that takes a lot of props. The component function will then be flooded with the default values. If possible, I'd like to define an `defaultProps` object which has all the expected default props defined so I can cleanup the component params.

Comment: Defining some sort of defaultProps object also makes is possible to share the same defaults between similar components, which use the same default props, but do different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const Component: FC<Props> = ({ foo = 'hello', bar = 'world' }) => {
```

The reason that code like this is recommended is because it's convenient. It's a nice shortcut for:

```
const Component: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const foo = props.foo === undefined ? 'hello' : props.foo;
  const bar = props.bar === undefined ? 'world' : props.bar;
```

But if you have something else you want to do, you can write different code. You say in the comments you want to have a predefined `defaultProps` object, which then gets applied to the missing props. That can be done like this (among other possibilities):

```
const defaultProps = {
  foo: 'hello',
  bar: 'world',
}

const Component: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const propsWithDefaults = {
    ...defaultProps,
    ...props,
  }

  const { foo, bar } = propsWithDefaults;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwGIGEC%20cBmUIjgcigFMBDAYxnwG4BYAKHuADsYipNyi4AFHMAZ0T04WCBAD8ALjj8YUZgHMANMLgAjElCky5ilXTT0jdMhCay4AEyIcArgBsYvCALgBeIXRGYx0-AAsie3sIfH0RDSg-AHdoe0sw%20kMGEzMLFFxIJiIWaVQAHmcBAD53OAAKMD5%20AEp3UoRVU3N4Kpd%20AHVgGH8AERsSBxhBD0avETgAOmnrO0ci-nCJ6cm2gSXkprT4BFEIJXVNOAwPNc7uvoGh-loUkWb%20CHsiSZCFcp8ISZgIAFUwMBsFAkfhEco1OoAekhcAAgsEINEiJYDmoiGRBqC4N18IJZsxukEAJ5wEg6eRMBRJIA)

If you want typescript to check the `defaultProps` object to make sure it doesn't have typos or extra properties and such, you can make use of the `satisfies` keyword (introduced in Typescript 4.9):

```
const defaultProps = {
  fo: 'hello', // <--- oops, typo
  bar: 'world',
  baz: 'so' // <--- oops, extra property
} satisfies Partial<Props>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=27&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwGIGEC%20cBmUIjgcigFMBDAYxnwG4BYAKHuADsYipNyi4AFHMAZ0T04WCBAD8ALjj8YUZgHMANMLgAjElCky5ilXTT0jdMhCay4AEyIcArgBsYvCALgBeIXRGYI0-AAsie3sIfCU4AHoIuAAeAFoEuDEBcJgAT0hVDSg-AHdoe0swrJIALz9%20UMjo%20MTk-nCiAA85EjgwPjZ0%20gx%20EhhgfkxgIkFuTQGSexjnAQA%20Y1NzeBRcSCYiFmlUGb5%20Ofc4AAoOl34ASncDhFUli1OBAHVgGH8AERsSBxhBDxuvERwAB0IOsdkcswaqhEIKBDyhAMMDABd3gCFEEHC2TgGA88Oerw%204J%20tGRIjuEHsRCBIQURx8ECBMAgAFUwGA2CgSPwiEdzpconAAILBCC5IiWLFEMhfHlwF74QRg5gvIJpOBtWTyJgKHpAA)

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work right? Both `foo` and `bar` are defined in `defaultProps`, but when destructuring the values from `propsWithDefaults` they are still shown as `string | undefined`, while undefined is impossible here.

Comment: I made a mistake which i've since edited. I originally gave defaultProps a type of `Partial<Props>`, and yes, with that you'd end up with `string | undefined`. But leave the type off (or if you prefer, define an explicit type where foo and bar are defined) and now typescript knows that foo and bar are defined.

Comment: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwGIGEC+cBmUIjgcigFMBDAYxnwG4BYAKHuADsYipNyi4AFHMAZ0T04WCBAD8ALjj8YUZgHMANMLgAjElCky5ilXTT0jdMhCay4AEyIcArgBsYvCALgBeIXRGYx0-AAsie3sIfH0RDSg-AHdoe0sw+kMGEzMLFFxIJiIWaVQAHmcBAD53OAAKMD5+AEp3UoRVU3N4Kpd+AHVgGH8AERsSBxhBD0avETgAOmnrO0ci-nCJ6cm2gSXkprT4BFEIJXVNOAwPNc7uvoGh-loUkWb+CHsiSZCFcp8ISZgIAFUwMBsFAkfhEco1OoAekhcAAgsEINEiJYDmoiGRBqC4N18IJZsxukEAJ5wEg6eRMBRJIA)

Comment: Aah I see. I made a mistake by also letting `defaultProps` have the type of `Props` (but these would then be set to optional). You're right, this would be a solution that works for me.

Comment: Thanks, with the `satisfies`, this is what I was looking for. It now also has type safety for defining the default props.

Comment: It's worth noting that with this answer, props explicitly set to undefined in components will overwrite your default props, unlike destructuring with defaults in the function definition.